# XMLHttpRequest: почему после отправки данных формы, страница все равно перезагружается?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Привет всем!
Пишу свою простенькую функцию для отправки данных из формы без перезагрузки страницы, но возникла проблема: после отправки данных через XMLHttpRequest страница все равно перезагружается (отправляет форму get-запросом). При этом сервер получает данные из формы, обрабатывает их и выдает соответствующий ответ.

Форма:

```
<form id="reg-form" onsubmit="sendForm(this.id, 'handler-url')>
<input type="text" name="data">
<button>Send</button>
```

Обработчик:

```
var sendForm = function (formId, url) {
    'use strict';
    var form = document.getElementById(formId);
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
       // При установке этого заголовка работа функции прекращается ошибкой
       // xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");

        xhr.open("POST", url, true);
        xhr.send(formData);

    if (xhr.status == 200) {
      alert("Worked!");
    } else {
      alert(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText+ 'Error');
    }
}
```

Сервер отвечает "OK", либо, если отправленные данные введены не правильно, отправляет json с описанием ошибок.
Но я в любом случае получаю в алерте: "0: Error" и после этого форма отправляется get-oм.

Помогите пожалуйста: как сделать что бы форма не отправлялась get-ом после XHR и почему я не могу получить от сервера ответ 200, хотя он отправляет его?

Answer (score 3):

Обработчик должен быть устроен так:

```
<form id="reg-form" onsubmit="sendForm(this.id, 'handler-url');event.preventDefault();">
```

Иначе сабмит идёт по встроенному сценарию после выполнения обработчика.

Comment: Спасибо, это действительно предотвращает отправку формы после выполнения обработчика.

Comment: Осталось узнать почему xhr.status всегда возвращает 0, а не реальный код ответа сервера.

Comment: @Роман Арсеньев  а это - потому что ajax обрабатывается асинхронно. Синхронная обрабока кажется была возможна, но принято асинхронно такое делать. См. onreadystatechange  - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/XMLHttpRequest .

Comment: @Роман Арсеньев а, понял, всё очень просто - третий параметр `.open` должен быть false. false - для синхронной, true - для асинхронной.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр, синхронная в некоторых браузерах может быть помечена как deprecated или удалена

Comment: @Igor это не глобальный event. Это то, что передаётся как аргумент в on* аттрибуты при происхождении события. Проверь `onclick="console.log(event);" ` .

Answer (score 3):

1 `return false;` внутри обработчика submit предполагает остановку отправки формы.

```
var sendForm = function (formId, url) {
    'use strict';
   // ... ваш код
   return false;// добавить
}
```

Но так как у вас ф-ция inline, то вам нужно поставить `onsubmit="return sendForm(this.id, 'handler-url');"` или `onsubmit="sendForm(this.id, 'handler-url'); return false;"`

2 Вам надо проверять готов ли ответ (отправка запроса занимает некоторое время) хотя бы так `while (xhr.readyState != 4);` А лучше делать так:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange= function(){
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
             // ....
           };
        }
    }
```

Comment: при inline обработчике `return false` из _sendForm_ недостаточно, нужно чтобы false вернулся из самого inline Обработчика

Comment: Да @Grundy, таки false с inline не передаётся.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что идет стандартная обработка события `submit`

Для предотвращения ее нужно либо вернуть `false` в inline обработчике

```
<form id="reg-form" onsubmit="return sendForm(this.id, 'handler-url')>
```

```js
var sendForm = function (formId, url) {
    'use strict';
    ...
    return false;
}
```

Либо вызвать [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

```
<form id="reg-form" onsubmit="sendForm(event, this.id, 'handler-url')>
```

```js
var sendForm = function (e, formId, url) {
    'use strict';
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
    return false;
}
```

Либо использовать [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) вместо inline обработчика

```
<form id="reg-form">
```

```js
document.getElementById('reg-form').addEventListener('click',function(){
    sendForm(this.id, 'handler-url');
    return false;
})
function sendForm(formId, url) {
    'use strict';
    ...
    return false;
}
```

или так

```
<form id="reg-form">
```

```js
document.getElementById('reg-form').addEventListener('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    sendForm(this.id, 'handler-url');
})
function sendForm(formId, url) {
    'use strict';
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо за участие, исходя из ваших ответов я "собрал" более оптимальный (все таки асинхронность более оптимальна) и более универсальный (inline-обработчик) способ отправки формы. Сам обработчик конечно еще не универсален, например, в него надо добавить поддержку IE, но первоначальная задача решена:

Форма:

```
<form id="reg-form" onsubmit="sendForm(this.id, 'handler-url'); event.preventDefault();> 
<input type="text" name="data">
<button>Send</button>
```

Обработчик:

```
var sendForm = function (formId, url) {
    'use strict';
    var form = document.getElementById(formId);
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.send(formData);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                alert("Worked!");
            } else {
                alert(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText + 'Error');
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: @Igor какой нафиг глобальный event, возмущённый вы знаток))

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр - точно, спасибо